# How to use offset on Telegram bot API webHook

Tags: api, telegram-bot

Since 2 days I've been exploring the Telegram bot API, which is pretty neat. But there is one thing I can't figure out.

When you don't use the webHook but the `/getUpdates` call, you can tell the API via the `offset` parameter which message where processed by the server.

But how do you do this with the webHook in place? I keep getting the same message as an update. Which results in the server spamming the user with the same message.

The solution I came up with is as follows:

1. Receive an update from the webhook
2. Save the `update_id`
3. Reply to the user `/sendMessage`
4. disable the webHook `/setWebhook?url=`
5. Set the offset `/getUpdates?offset={update_id+1}`
6. Reinstate the webHook `/setWebhook?url=https://mywebhook.domain.com`

There must be a better way right? Anyone?

Comment: Rather, you keep the webhook as-is and your webhook handling code keeps track of last update and skips the ones already processed

Comment: That was my first thought as well. But on the `/getUpdate` call I could see that in my testcase there where more than 10 messages, while the webHook only gave me 1 message at a time. Always the same message (the first one of the `/getUpdate` call). 

And on the Telegram server kept sending updates to my server, even if all relevant messages had been handled (replied to).

Comment: true, but the `/getupdates` call should be returning a `update_id` in every message. Keep a track of the last `update_id` in your local side and if the `update_id` is lesser than the saved id, you can assume it's handled

Comment: Yes, but there is a problem with that approach. If somebody sends a message to my bot, the webHook calls my server every 2 seconds with that particular message. 
If somebody else sends a message to my bot, I never receive that message. Only the first one (which I receive every 2 seconds).
So user A sends me "/start" en 10 sec later user B sends me "/something", the webhook only sends me the "/start" message, and nothing else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. It appeared that just a 200 (OK) wasn't enough (the body of my response was *null*. I've added a body to the response `{}`, and know it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

You must say to telegram that you get updates successfully with this:

```
 - 200 response code
 &
 - empty json like this {}
```

Answer (score 2):

use This on webHook to get data from telegram servers:

```
// get the raw POST data
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");

// this returns null if not valid json
$jsonData = json_decode($rawData);
```

Answer (score 1):

What HTTP status code are you returning on the page handling your webhook? It is possible that Telegram is attempting to retry your webhook endpoint because it's not receiving a status 200 (OK) from you.

Comment: The webhook returns a 200 with no body. So that couldn't be it, or your are required to return something, but I can't find what.